# Mongo $in query works in standalone mongo instance but not in AWS DocumentDB instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongodb-query, aws-documentdb

```
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
    {
      $project: {
        "has books" : 
          { $in: ["A", {$cond: {if: {$gt: ["$books", null]}, then: "$books", else: []}}] }
      }
    }
])
```

The above query works when executed on a standalone MongoDB and gives the following result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca6023ccb9228c0ab417ad5"),
    "has books" : false
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca631b8cb9228c0ab419174"),
    "has books" : false
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca64006cb9228c0ab419a54"),
    "has books" : false
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca6e093cb9228c0ab41cf7c"),
    "has books" : true
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ca6eee9cb9228c0ab41d594"),
    "has books" : false
}
```

However, on executing the same query on AWS DocumentDB instance the following error is given:

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: object",
    "code" : 40081
} : aggregate failed 
Details:
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:534:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:618:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:260:9
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1062:12
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1
```

The aim of the query is to check if a particular value is present in the array or not, with the output expected as boolean. The`docs` collection has an array field = `books` which can be null, so to overcome the null issue, `$cond` is used to replace `books` field with an empty array if the field does not exist or is null.
`$ifNull` is not supported by AWS DocumentDB so it cannot be used.

Suggestions to correct the above query or use an alternative query which will be supported by AWS DocumentDB to get the expected result will be of immense help.

Comment: maybe change `$gt` to `$ne` first?

Comment: tried, same thing happens using `$ne`

Comment: Make sure the field is well defined on all documents, `undefined` !== `null`.

Comment: checked for undefined field, and there are none.

Comment: Just making sure you checked using `books: {$exits: false}`?

Comment: Another thing to check is that all `book` are type array. use `$type` to do it.

Comment: with `books: {$exits: false}` i got documents which didn't have the field and I also checked with `{books: {$type: 6}` which gave me 0 documents.

Comment: 6 is deprecated. if you got documents with `{$exists: false}` then it means that's the problem. i'll write an answer with a solution to bypass it\

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you have `books` field that's neither `null` nor an array.

You can work around this by using [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) like so:

```
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "has books" :
                { $in: ["A", {$cond: {if: {$ne: [{$ifNull: ["$books", null]}, null]}, then: "$books", else: []}}] }
        }
    }
])
```

Or using [$isArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isArray/):

```
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "has books" :
                { $in: ["A", {$cond: {if: {$isArray: "$books"}, then: "$books", else: []}}] }
        }
    }
])
```

Or without using any of these operators because they're not supported then you can add a `type` field and then continue:

```
db.getCollection('docs').aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            booksType: {$type: "$books"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "has books" :
                { $in: ["A", {$cond: {if: {$eq: ["$booksType", 4]}, then: "$books", else: []}}] }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: As mentioned above, `$ifNull` is not supported by AWS DocumentDB so it cannot be used:(

Comment: what about `$isArray` as i added to my answer?

Comment: all of the above is not working for DocumentDB instance but is working for mongodb standalone instance.

Comment: I added another version that's less "sexy" looking but does not utilize any operator that's not supported.

Comment: $ifNull support was added to Amazon DocumentDB in January 2021.